# Ruby - Select Array Entry With Most Recent Date

Tags: ruby, datetime, select

How do I return just the hash with the most recent datetime?

```
list = [ { info: "i am cool", datetime: June 25 5 pm},
         { info: "this is sweet", datetime: June 25 4 pm},
         { info: "it is blue", datetime: June 23 2 pm} ]
```

Comment: `June 25 5 pm` is not a valid object. Do you mean it to be a string?

Comment: no, sorry, that was psuedo-code.  it is meant to be a valid datetime instance

Comment: Then write `list = [ { info: "i am cool", datetime: #<DateTime: 2015-06-25T17:00:00+00:00 ((2457199j,61200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, ...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array#max_by`:

```
list.max_by {|o| o[:datetime]}
```

Comment: This does not return the most recent date, it returns the newest date. Most recent would infer that the date returned is always in the past.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for this answer five years later, here you go:

```
list.filter {|o| o[:datetime] < Date.today}.max
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the block form of [`Array#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-sort) to sort them by `datetime`, and then get the last one.

```
require 'date'

list = [
  { datetime: DateTime.parse("June 25 5pm"), info: "i am cool" },
  { datetime: DateTime.parse("June 25 4pm"), info: "this is sweet" },
  { datetime: DateTime.parse("June 23 2pm"), info: "it is blue" }
]

list.sort do |a, b|
  a[:datetime] <=> b[:datetime]
end.last
```

Comment: Sorting is waseful when you only need the element for which a computed value is largest or smallest. Here use [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).